# I Get an Error, but the Build Runs Correctly

Tags: android, flutter, dart

### The Problem

I get an error with `$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`, but I don't know what the error is. I checked an app with my Android device, the build looks good.

### What I Did

- Installed [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/install).

  dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^8.2.6
- Set `compileSdkVersion` of `android/app/build.gradle` 31 from 30.
- Added `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` inside `<manifest ....>` of `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

### Log

```
$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 5a in debug mode...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in D:\Android\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 31 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 31 in D:\Android\platforms\android-31
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" finished.
����:D:\src\flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java�̑���́A���`�F�b�N�܂��͈��S�ł͂���܂���B
����:�ڍׂ́A-Xlint:unchecked�I�v�V�������w�肵�čăR���p�C�����Ă��������B
����:�ꕔ�̓��̓t�@�C���͐�������Ȃ�API���g�p�܂��̓I�[�o�[���C�h���Ă��܂��B
����:�ڍׂ́A-Xlint:deprecation�I�v�V�������w�肵�čăR���p�C�����Ă��������B
����:���̓t�@�C���̑���̂����A���`�F�b�N�܂��͈��S�ł͂Ȃ����̂�����܂��B
����:�ڍׂ́A-Xlint:unchecked�I�v�V�������w�肵�čăR���p�C�����Ă��������B
����:�ꕔ�̓��̓t�@�C���͐�������Ȃ�API���g�p�܂��̓I�[�o�[���C�h���Ă��܂��B
����:�ڍׂ́A-Xlint:deprecation�I�v�V�������w�肵�čăR���p�C�����Ă��������B
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            112.1s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...              1,910ms
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\FlutterProjects\test\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.tester.test   
signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following in the logcat points out the problem:

```
adb: failed to install D:\FlutterProjects\test\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.tester.test   
signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

The app that you are trying to install has a different signature than the one that is already installed on the device. That's why the new version cannot be installed as an update to the existing app. I have faced this too.

Just uninstall the app from the device, and again execute as usual. The problem should be solved.

Comment: This solved the issue! thank you so much!